# Subset one column from data frame keeping the subset as a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a table containing filters, such as

```
> X = data.frame(filter1=c(1,1,1),filter2=c(1,1,0),filter3=c(1,0,0))
> X
  filter1 filter2 filter3
1       1       1       1
2       1       1       0
3       1       0       0
```

I like to select the filters based on conditionals:

```
> selected_filters = c(1:2)
> X[,paste0("filter",c(selected_filters))]
  filter1 filter2
1       1       1
2       1       1
3       1       0
```

However, if I have only one column selected, the data frame converts into a list

```
> selected_filters = c(2)
> X[,paste0("filter",c(selected_filters))]
[1] 1 1 0
```

How to select also only one column keeping the result as a data frame? Desired result would look like

```
  filter2
1       1
2       1
3       0
```

Comment: Part of the problem was actually to try to find the correct documentation, because it is not obvious that for the square bracket syntax `X[...]` one cannot look for help using syntax `?[]`. As @acrun points out in his answer, one should seek for help with syntax `?Extract`.

Comment: We can get help as with any other function: `?"["` will take us to *Extract* manual.  Similarly `?"+"` would take us to *Arithmetic*, etc.

Comment: Note that you can use `selected_filters` instead of `c(selected_filters)` in the solutions proposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `drop = FALSE`

```
X[, paste0("filter",c(selected_filters)), drop = FALSE]
#   filter2
#1       1
#2       1
#3       0
```

---

If we look at `?Extract`, the Usage shows

> x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]

and in the description, it says

> drop - For matrices and arrays. If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension (see the examples). This only works for extracting elements, not for the replacement. See drop for further details.

---

Note that `subset` behavior is different because it is by default `drop = FALSE`

```
subset(X, select = paste0("filter",c(selected_filters)))
```

Comment: I am not sure If my answer is the same as yours...i.e. `drop = TRUE` is the same as selecting without the comma...?

Comment: @Sotos, No, it is fine :=)

Answer (score 2):

You will get a data frame If you avoid the comma.

```
X[paste0("filter", c(selected_filters))]
#  filter2
#1       1
#2       1
#3       0

str(X[paste0("filter", c(selected_filters))])
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ filter2: num  1 1 0

str(X[,paste0("filter", c(selected_filters))])
 num [1:3] 1 1 0
```